# Lightning bolt then system crash. Only red light is on

Tags: raspbian, crash, power-light

I was using my pi 3 with the official power supply and compatible[image] keyboard and mouse. I was just using geany like I normally would when the lightning bolt appeared  (the sign for overloading the pi) and then the screen turned blank. Now it won't  boot and the red light shows. I have another pi which I have put the sd card Into and the card still works. Any ideas on how to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: The lightning bolt symbol is an indication that you're *under*-powering your Pi, rather than overpowering it. See: [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/what-does-the-lightning-bolt-mean/57965#57965).

Comment: @goobering I said overloading. I.e there wasn't enough power to run which is also underpowering.

Comment: No need to act like that. It is probably a power problem, that resulted in the Pi shutting off.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I have tried different power supplies and sd cards and also other peripherals since this and the pi just will not boot. Also I didn't intend to come across as aggressive.

Comment: Did you short the pi? Or damage it by under powering it? I read something about that being a source of damage.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen i have a case on the pi so i cant access the gpio pins. This rules out shorting I think. I doubt that I underpowered it as i am using the recommended supply from the pi foundation. However there could have been a fault in that supply leading to underpowering or shorting.

Comment: Open up the case, post pictures. There really isn't much information for us to work on. Did you try the non logical answers like another SD(I know your SD card works on other PIs) or whatever. Just disconnect everything and connecting it again? Did you try another power supply? There are lots of things you could try and maybe there is a flaw somewhere. Or maybe you had a bad Pi that is the root of your problems.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen i have tried some different peripherals and they don't work. I've used other sd cards and also a different power supply.  I will post some pictures shortly.

Answer (score 4):

it probably is a power supply problem.

The allowed voltage range is the normal one (for 5V logic) 5.0V ±5%
so its a the range between 4.75V and 5.25V.
Note that the lower limit of 4.75V is more a matter of many USB devices not working below that value than it is that the PI itself is that sensitive, especially as much of it (including the ethernet/hub chip, and the SD-card) is working from 3,3V through a regulator on board of the PI that will keep working even with say 4.0V.

Also note that many 5V logic devices will be damaged by voltages of 6.5V or higher! Therefore there is a protection device on the PI (D17) that will short the 5V supply if about 6.0V is supplied! Then the (poly)fuse will blow out to protect D17 from burning up! If you do not power the PI through the normal micro-USB port then you are actually bypassing that fuse!

there is a section of the PI Wiki at http://elinux.org/RaspberryPiBoard dedicated to boot problems like this.

Comment: Ok so my poly fuse has probably just blown

Comment: @that_raspberry_pi_guy But why would that situation have arisen on your Pi?

Comment: @joan I don't know. My cpu temperatures escalated and then it just showed the power supply overload. I wondered if there was an error in the cpu that drew a lot of power and got very hot. Now it is not doing anything but thankfully my sd  card is unharmed

Comment: The red led is part of the 3.3V system and so **could not be on** if the polyfuse were blown https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-3B-V1_2-SCHEMATIC-REDUCED.pdf <- The fuse ("MF-MSMF250/X") is top left, the leds are in the second row on the right.

Comment: @goldilocks ok, so this points away from the cause being a short?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There could still have been a short that actually damaged the Pi, if it bypassed the polyfuse, etc.   But if nothing helps you could cross your fingers, leave it for a few days, and see.

Comment: There also might be something loose on the board touching where it shouldn't be touched.  Make sure there is no FOD (Foreign Object Debris), in other words.