# 5.6V with official touchscreen

Tags: power, power-supply, touchscreen

As I [mentioned earlier](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77008/low-power-warning-using-touch-screen) I am getting low power warnings with a 5V adapter, and have now obtained another one that says 5.6V. Am wondering if this might work, or if it will damage the Pi and/or the touchscreen. Google gives conflicting information. Either the Pi will not survive more than 5.25V, or it will run happily on up to 7.5V.

Is there an authoritative explanation of the power requirements of the combined Pi 3 and official touchscreen?

Comment: You would benefit from reading the [Official Power Requirements](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#power). Do not power the Pi with anything more than 5V. If you are experiencing power issues it is more likely you are not supplying enough current. Get a high quality USB power adapter that supplies 5V and is rated up to 2.5A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get an official answer.

The USB specs says 5V +/- 0.25V.  That covers everything connected to the Pi via USB.

The Pi itself will run from a voltage in the range slightly larger than 3V3 to slightly less than 6V (connected to a 5V pin on the expansion header).  The highest voltage I have risked is 5.8V.