# lightning bolt on first powerup

Tags: power-supply

I purchased the CANAKIT Raspberry pi with the Canakit power supply. I purchased the pre-loaded microsd card.
On first power up I got the rainbow and the lightning bolt (no menu)
I've tried 3 alternate power supplies and plugging the usb cable into my computer USB port.   No change!

Comment: sounds like a bad power supply .... your computer's usb port has its output current limited to 500mA by design, therefore it does not have the capacity to power an RPi

Comment: If you have a multimeter handy, try checking the [voltage across the Pi](https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#How_can_I_tell_if_the_power_supply_is_inadequate.3F) to see if the power supply is within range. Also, perhaps [edit] your question to include what version of Pi you have, and what rating your power supply has (it will probably have voltage/current ratings on the plug itself).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the lightning bolt mean?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/what-does-the-lightning-bolt-mean)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bad contact in microUSB socket on Raspberry Pi.